# Is it possible to consume an XML RPC service using a basic HTTP request?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I've been tasked to consume an XML RPC API, and I'm quite unfamiliar with it. I've glanced around a few pages describing it, and I've seen there's a few libraries out there as well.

However, it's left me with a feeling that all it comes down to is posting an HTTP request, similar to REST, except using XML in the body as opposed to JSON.

I imagine constructing an HTTP request similar to the below:

```
POST /path/service.cfm HTTP/1.0
From: example@example.com
User-Agent: whatever/1.0
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 155

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>examples.getStateName</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
        <value><i4>40</i4></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

Am I on the right track? The abundance of libraries around give me the feeling that perhaps it's more complicated than what I thought. Ideally I'd like to write a quick client in .NET myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          HttpWebRequest request = BuildWebRequest();

          var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
          var responseContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    }

    private static HttpWebRequest BuildWebRequest()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Timeout = 40000;
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;

        string body = @"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>examples.getStateName</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
        <value><i4>40</i4></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(body);

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        return request;
    }
```

Yes it is not a problem, here is an example how to do it. In string body you must write only your xml and you should put the correct content type. If the service provider have requirements like specific Headers you should add them.

Comment: Ah yes, this is exactly what I was going for. So you've used this on an XML RPC service before?

Comment: @drminnaar you can accept my answer if you help you.